# Dropdown chevron not rotating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, rotation, icons, dropdown

I have a dropdown and want a chevron to rotate when the link is clicked on. At the moment this works in codepen. But when I transfer this to the website I am working on, the chevron will not move. What would be the best way to test and fix this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/ryannewell/u4om0Lac/16/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 <title>Chevron</title>
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/js/all.js">
</script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <style>
.icon-rotates {
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
}

.icon-rotates.rotate {
  -moz-transition: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition: rotate(180deg);
  transition: rotate(180deg);
}
    </head>
```

Contact Links

dropdown

```
    <script>
$('.contact-link').click(function(){

  if($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
    $(this).children().css('transform', 'rotate(180deg)');
  } else {
    $(this).children().css('transform', 'none');
  }

});
$(".dropdown").on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function(){
        $(this).find('.contact-link').children().css('transform', 'none');
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've updated this now. The chevron rotates when clicking the link, but in my solution I need date-toggle="collapse" instead of data-toggle="dropdown". When I change this to collapse it stops working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you copied and pasted exactly as you have it in your actual code (not CodePen), but in your example code, your CSS and JavaScript are not within style or script tags.

Comment: The chevron will animate in codepen but not in my project. What would be the best way to problem solve this? How can I add an alert to the jquery to see if it works in my project?

Comment: I know there's an issue with rotating font icons but I don't know the reason. You should be able to wrap the chevron icon in another div, give that wrapper div the class of rotate, and it should work. Also, in your code example above, you haven't imported jQuery at all.

Comment: Ok thanks Dan Buda, I tried that but the chevron stopped rotating

Comment: I've updated to this link but need the chevron to rotate with data-toggle="collape" http://jsfiddle.net/ryannewell/u4om0Lac/16/